# Create a Bokeh DataTable from a "transposed" ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to link a DataTable to a figure with multiple lines in a way that is easier on the eyes for the DataTable. Consider the following example:

```html
'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>0.5</th>\n      <th>0.75</th>\n      <th>0.9</th>\n      <th>0.95</th>\n      <th>0.99</th>\n      <th>A</th>\n      <th>B</th>\n      <th>C</th>\n      <th>D</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1121045</th>\n      <td>75</td>\n      <td>90</td>\n      <td>103</td>\n      <td>112</td>\n      <td>124.63</td>\n      <td>x</td>\n      <td>a</td>\n      <td>alpha</td>\n      <td>2019-07-18 00:00:00</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1121529</th>\n      <td>77</td>\n      <td>92</td>\n      <td>105.3</td>\n      <td>114.65</td>\n      <td>992.95</td>      <td>x</td>\n      <td>a</td>\n      <td>alpha</td>\n      <td>2019-07-21 00:00:00</td>    </tr>\n    <tr>      <th>4006922</th>\n      <td>69</td>      <td>86</td>      <td>101</td>      <td>106</td>      <td>116</td>      <td>y</td>      <td>b</td>      <td>beta</td>      <td>2019-07-14 00:00:00</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>4006926</th>      <td>83</td>      <td>91</td>      <td>112</td>      <td>121</td>      <td>166</td>      <td>y</td>      <td>b</td>      <td>gamma</td>      <td>2019-07-14 00:00:00</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>4006927</th>      <td>55</td>      <td>63</td>      <td>72</td>      <td>81</td>      <td>100</td>      <td>y</td>      <td>c</td>     <td>beta</td>     <td>2019-07-14 00:00:00</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>'
```

Currently, I am plotting lines corresponding to the columns `[0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99]`, but this is done "row-wise," i.e. one line per index element. This is being achieved by taking a `CDSView` of the transpose of this dataframe. Essentially, I am turning the index into columns and filtering out `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` for the line plot.

I would like to make a DataTable that looks like the above table, using the same underlying `ColumnDataSource` in order to preserve linked selection behavior.

Alternatively, is there an equivalent to a "RowDataSource?" I am not aware of such a mechanism, but that would solve this problem from the plotting angle (as opposed to the DataTable angle).